# Join Tables to find SUM for Points available and points completed

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have three tables: Achievements, Characters, and Character_Achievements table that store's the ID's of completed achievements and user id. I am looking to get each category, total amount of points possible and also the amount completed.

I am able to get each category and the amount of points possible but I am unsuccessful at retrieving the completed count as well.

I currently use this to get each category and the amount of points possible

```
SELECT achievements.category, SUM(points) AS Total
FROM achievements
GROUP BY achievements.category ORDER BY achievements._id asc
```

I get these results.

```
Category    Total
Operations   50
Events       25
```

I can also get the amount of points completed

```
SELECT achievements.category, SUM(points) AS Completed
FROM achievements
LEFT JOIN character_achievements
ON character_achievements.achievements_id = achievements._id
LEFT JOIN character
ON character_achievements.character_id = character._id
WHERE character._id = '1'
```

which returns this but only the categories that are completed. How do I combine these two queries together.
    Category    Completed
    Operations   50
    Events       25

I've tried UNION but it does not return the results I need.
Here are my example tables

**Achievements Table**

```
Category        Title               Points
Operations      Epic Enemies          25
Operations      Explosive Conflict    25
Events          Bounty Contract       25
```

**Character_Achievements Table**

```
Character        Character_id       Achievements_id
Operations              1               1
Events                  1               3
```

The results I'm looking for would like this.

**Results**

```
Category    Completed   Total
Operations     25         50
Events         25         25
```

I am able

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can use `SUM` with `CASE`:

```
SELECT  a.category, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ca.achievements_id is not null then points end) AS Completed,
    SUM(points) Total
FROM achievements a
    LEFT JOIN character_achievements ca
        ON ca.achievements_id = a._id
GROUP BY a.category 
ORDER BY a._id asc
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate the ridiculously quick and great answer :)